# Magento 2.3 : In API Cart Items are clear when payment failed

Tags: magento2, api, payment, shopping-cart

**Cart items  clear before payment success if the payment is failed then cart products are cleared in API**. Actually I need  **if payment is failed the product no need to remove from carts** this case working in web but not in API !!. how can i solve this problem in Magento 2.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset your cart using the following code.

```
$quotefactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory');
$quote = $quotefactory->create()->load('your_quote_id');
$quote->setIsActive(true);
$quote->save();
```

NB: I used object manager as a reference. Do not use object manager in your code.

Comment: Thanks @dhanus , let me check

Comment: Okay, let me know if you have any queries on this.

Comment: Great!! its working  Thank you @dhanus